# Как написать программу, которая определит сходится ли пасьянс?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Задача:

> На столе лежат колоды игральных карт. В самой тоненькой колоде – p карт, во второй – p+1, в третьей – p+2, …, в последней – k карт. Старуха Шапокляк раскладывает пасьянс. Беря в руки любую из колод, она, если число карт в ней четное, на место возвращает колоду, наполовину уменьшив число карт в ней (лишние убирает в ящик), а если количество карт в колоде нечетное, то утраивает их количество и добавляет еще одну карту, а уже тогда кладет колоду на стол (карт у нее в ящике для этой операции достаточно). Если в какой-то колоде остается две карты, она больше ее не трогает. Пасьянс сходится, если во всех колодах остается по две карты.
>
> Требуется написать программу, которая определит сходится ли пасьянс, и если сходится – сколько раз должна старуха Шапокляк брать со стола карты.
>
> Входные данные
> Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит 2 числа, записанные через пробел (2 ≤ p < k < 1000).
>
> Выходные данные
> Выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT должен содержать 0, если пасьянс не сходится, и, если сходится, количество «ходов» старухи Шапокляк.

Мой код:

```
var
a,b,c,i:integer;

begin
c:=0;
read(a,b);

while a <> 2 do begin
if a mod 2 = 0 then a:=a div 2
               else a:=a*3+1;
c:=c+1;               
end;
 
while b <> 2 do begin
if b mod 2 = 0 then b:=b div 2
               else b:=b*3+1;
c:=c+1;               
end; 

writeln(c);
end.
```

При введённых числах 5 и 8 получается 6, а в примере к решению ответ 28.

Comment: По-моему, проще заранее просчитать те значения, для которых ответ отрицателен, и количество шагов для тех, для которых ответ положителен, захардкодить это, и просто проверять/считать сумму.

Comment: *При введённых числах 5 и 8 получается 6, а в примере к решению ответ 28* Считать надо не только для `a` и `b` (в условии - `p` и `k`), но и для всех промежуточных...

Comment: Вообще то такой пасьянс всегда будет сходиться. Нужно только считать за какое число шагов он сходится. Это одна из нерешенных проблем математики которая называется Гипотеза Коллатца и числа до 87 * 2^60 проверены на сходимость.

Answer (score 0):

Объясните словами логику решения. Что предполагается делать, если пасьянс не сходится? Возможно ли это? Почему Вы проверяете только два числа - `a` и `b`? Где цикл по колодам?

```
p = 5, k = 8 - четыре колоды

5: 16 8 4 2 - 4 хода
6: 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 - 7 ходов
7: 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 - 15 ходов
8: 4 2 - 2 хода

Всего: 28 ходов
```

Вы проверяете только первую и последнюю колоды: `4 + 2 = 6 ходов`.